# c++ create a class, call its funcion and push back to vector in one statement

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class `MyClass` and another class that holds an array of `MyClass`, as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    float b;

    void SetInt(int value)
    {
        a = value;
    }

    void SetFloat(float value)
    {
        b = value;
    }
}

class MyClassArray {
    std::vector<MyClass> classList;
}
```

What is the easier way to create a new `MyClass`, insert an object in `MyClassArray` and call the methods to store value on it ?

Can I just create a temporary `MyClass` and insert it on the vector, calling the function in one statement ? Like:

```
classList.push_back(MyClass().SetInt(21));
classList.push_back(MyClass().SetFloat(1.23));
```

Is that valid ?

BTW: I need in `vector` a one object `MyClass` with `21` set on `a` and another one with `1.23` set on `b`, that´s why I´m not using initializers for `a` and `b`.

Comment: I don't understand. You don't know the datatype by the opening parenthesis of `MyClass()`, but you do know it by the time you get to the dot after `MyClass()`?

Comment: No. Forget about this last comment.. I just removed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `chaining` :

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    float b;
public:
    MyClass& Set(int value)   { a = value; return *this; }
    MyClass& Set(float value) { b = value; return *this; }
};
```

this enables thing like:

```
MyClass a;
a.Set(1).Set(1.5f);
```

and also:

```
vector<MyClass> vec;
vec.push_back(MyClass{}.Set(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Use your constructor 
    class MyClass {
        int a;
        float b;


    }

class MyClassArray {
    std::vector<MyClass> classList;
    classList.push_back(MyClass(21,1.23));
}
```

Comment: what a beautiful leak!

Comment: vector Doesn't need to (and probably shouldn't) store  pointers.

Comment: This won´t work, as I need 2 different classes on `vector`. One with `21` set at `a` and the other with `1.23` set at `b`. That way I´ll have one class with both `a` and `b` set.

Comment: @Mendez then you need even more constructors

Comment: You don't need a pointer then simple I assumed the OP will have the sense to free the vector after wards . Edited if you don't want pointers . std vector destructor calls the destructor of its constituent objects

Comment: user3528438 what do you mean by a leak kindly explain

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructors for this. If you overload the constructor to take either an `int` or a `float` you would be able to set the value for both of the situations that you outlined.

```
class MyClass 
{
    int a;
    float b;

    MyClass(int i) : a(i) { }
    MyClass(float f) : b(f) { }
}
```

this way you could add objects to the `vector` by doing this:

```
std::vector<MyClass> classList;

classList.push_back(MyClass(21));
```

and by doing this:

```
classList.push_back(MyClass(1.23));
```

If you really need to call a separate method you could do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    float b;

    MyClass& SetInt(int value)
    {
        a = value;
        return *this;
    }

    MyClass& SetFloat(float value)
    {
        b = value;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Which will return a reference to the class. It is far better to do it using constructors though.

Comment: Using constructors can be a problem. What if I call MyClass(10). The constructor will never know if I´m calling for Int or for Float and may cause wrong call...

Comment: The constructor will know. If you wanted a float, your certainly would have used MyClass(10.0)... so it must be an int. ;-)

Comment: @Mendez If you call `MyClass(10)` the compiler will deduce that you intended it to be an int. If you call `MyClass(10.0)` the compiler will deduce that you intended it to be a float.

Comment: It will not know in the case mentioned.... I cannot guarantee all inputted values will have a dot. This is assuming possible failures, for me a bad practice in this case.

Comment: So you cannot guarantee that the inputted values will have a dot, but you can guarantee, that the correct function is used? Strange.

Comment: If you want to have different function names for the constructors, a possible solution is to use static member functions that forward to the - private! - constructor: `MyClass CreateFromFloat(float value) { return MyClass(value); }`. Which then can be used like this: `classList.push_back(MyClass::CreateFromFloat(10));`.

Comment: If that is true, it may be better for you to use the second method. But, if you are changing your function calls, it would seem to be easier to add a dot where appropriate anyway.